# Find the position of All occurrences of a column values in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", "X-X-------------------------------X--X---XX-X--X-------")],["id", "value"])
```

From above dataframe,  find all occurrences of `X` for column value

**Expected output:**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | [1, 3, 35, 38, 42, 43, 45, 48] |

Comment: Getting this error An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Comment: there may be null values in the dataset .You may check the parameter value accepted by the UDF it is `None` first before iterating eg `if  str_val is None: return [] `

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a custom udf to achieve this eg

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))
def udf_val_indexes(str_val):
    indexes = []
    for index,val in enumerate(str_val):
        if val=="X":
            indexes.append(index+1)
    return indexes

df.withColumn("value",udf_val_indexes(F.col("value"))).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |value                         |
+---+------------------------------+
|A  |[1, 3, 35, 38, 42, 43, 45, 48]|
+---+------------------------------+
```

or split by your character and with the assistance of posexplode, sum to find the indexes before grouping them to one row as shown below.

NB. The order by clauses help to maintain the order of the indexes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
(
    df.withColumn("val_split",F.split("value","X"))
      .select(
          F.col("id"),
          F.posexplode("val_split") 
      )
      .withColumn("row_pos_to_exclude",F.max("pos").over(Window.partitionBy("id")))
      .filter(F.col("pos") != F.col("row_pos_to_exclude") )
      .withColumn("val_split_len",F.length("col")+1)
      .withColumn(
          "val_split_len",
          F.sum("val_split_len").over(
              Window.partitionBy("id")
                    .orderBy("pos")
                    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
          )
      )
      .withColumn(
          "value",
          F.collect_list("val_split_len").over(
              Window.partitionBy("id")
                    .orderBy("pos")
          )
      )
      .groupBy("id")
      .agg(
          F.max("value").alias("value")
      )
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |value                         |
+---+------------------------------+
|A  |[1, 3, 35, 38, 42, 43, 45, 48]|
+---+------------------------------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.